# How to use more than 255 fields in a report query ms access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an Access database that pulls data in from a linked Excel spreadsheet.  I have made some queries to filter out the data that I want.  I want all the data to populate a report.  In the report I open up the Record Source, which opens up the Query Builder.  I have brought in all of the queries that I am using and then add only the fields of the queries that are needed to populate the report.  I have then link each Control Source in the report with the corresponding field from the Query Builder.  The problem I am running into is that I have a total of 257 fields in the Query Builder and it appears that you can only have 255. If I delete 2 of the fields everything works, but as soon as I bring in the last 2 to make a total of 257 everything in the report gets the Green Triangle saying Invalid Control Property: Control Source.  If I delete 2 fields all the Green Triangles go away.  Why is this and is there a work around for this?
Thanks in advanced for any help on this!

Comment: Perhaps you could use `DLookup()` expressions to populate the last two controls (fields) on the report.

Comment: I was unable to get the DLookup() to work for these fields, but thanks for the suggestion.